# Create a dummy out of the 5% percentiles

Tags: r

I performed a regression which returns me residuals as a zoo object.

Now I wish to create a dummy out of these residuals, taking the value of 1 if these belong to the upper 5% or the lower 5% of all residuals, and 0 otherwise.

I know how to do it for specific value (e.g. if I want all residuals smaller than 0.03 to be equal to 1 and 0 otherwise: `dummy <- ifelse(residuals <= -0.03, 1, 0)`) but not for a precise percentile.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [`quantile`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) function:

```
xx <- rnorm(1000)

perc_dummy <- ifelse(xx <= quantile(xx, .05), 1,
                     ifelse(xx >= quantile(xx, .95), 1, 0))

table(perc_dummy)
# perc_dummy
#   0   1 
# 900 100
```

One-liner as suggested by Konrad Rudolph

```
perc_dummy = as.numeric(xx <= quantile(xx, 0.05) | xx >= quantile(xx, 0.95))
```

Comment: Instead of nested `ifelse` you could also do `perc_dummy = xx <= quantile(xx, 0.05) | xx >= quantile(xx, 0.95)`.

Comment: good suggestion. OP wants a 1/0 dummy variable, so I would wrap that in `as.numeric`

Answer (score 0):

R has a separate logical data type that can be used instead of encoding these as numbers. So I would generally write

```
dummy = data <= quantile(data, 0.05) | data >= quantile(data, 0.95)
```

However, if you insist on 0/1 instead, you can convert the above trivially using `as.integer()` or `as.numeric()` or `ifelse()`.

An alternative solution, which allows treating lower and upper percentiles uniformly, uses `cut()`:

```
cut(data, c(-Inf, quantile(data, c(0.05, 0.95)), Inf), labels = c(1L, 0L, 1L))
```

However, beware that the result of this is a `factor`, so even though the values are labelled as `0` and `1`, their underlying values are actually `1L` and `2L`, in arbitrary order.

Furthermore, the `cut()` solution requires adding `Inf`inity to make it work. So in practice this solution is fairly messy even though it’s conceptually a good fit (`findInterval()`, which is a simplified `cut()`, doesn’t require adding `Inf`inite bounds; but conversely it doesn’t allow assigning lower and upper percentiles to the same group — this would require an extra step).